# how to stack image files in to one file and how to resize black and white images

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, opencv, python

here my images look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipSLu.jpg)
I am trying to stack the images files into one file and also resizing black white images 1000X1000. But I didn't get, I have images with size 600X400, but I need it's to 1000 pixels size, please help me how to do.
Here my images loading:

```
 import cv2
    import glob
    img= [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack1/*jpg')]
img2= [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack2/*jpg')]
img3= [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack3/*jpg')]
img4= [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack4/*jpg')]
```

here I am taking all images into one list:

```
img=img1+img2+img3+img4
```

Here my resize the images :

```
im_g=cv2.resize(img,(1000,1000))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-56a6794f0ec5> in <module>()
----> 1 im_g=cv2.resize(img,(1000,1000))

TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Comment: Did you realise that indentation is significant in Python?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, img1, img2, img3, img4 are lists. When you use the + operator, they are stacked in the list way.

For example, N images with size (h,w) in each folder (stack1, stack2, ...), the shape of img1 is (N, h, w). However, the shape of img1+img2 is (2N, h, w). Use numpy array instead.

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

img1 = np.array([cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack1/*jpg')])
img2 = np.array([cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack2/*jpg')])
img3 = np.array([cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack3/*jpg')])
img4 = np.array([cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack4/*jpg')])

imgs = list(img1+img2+img3+img4)

for img in imgs:
    im_g = cv2.resize(img,(1000,1000))
```

How many files are there in the folder (stack1, stack2, ...)?
In your way of using glob, the result will be multiple files. You have to add one more step that stack files in the folder.

If the desired result is only one file, try this.

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

img1 = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack1/*jpg')]
img2 = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack2/*jpg')]
img3 = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack3/*jpg')]
img4 = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/NanduCn/jupter1/deepl/challenges-master/ML/stack4/*jpg')]

imgs = (img1+img2+img3+img4)
stacked_img = np.array(img1[0])
for img in imgs[1:]:
    stacked_img += np.array(img)
im_g = cv2.resize(stacked_img,(1000,1000))
```

Note: you may want to normalize(average) the value of the stacked image.